# Unpack C++ array to arguments on a function call

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a library capable of understanding Godot's RPC requests.

From the RPC request, I have made an array of arguments of arbitrary size. The arguments are all of the same type, `Variant`. Each `Variant` contains a `type` enum and casting overloading to return the proper type, be it an `int` or a `const char*`, etc.

Now, I'd like to have the library accept registrations of function points, or `std::function` instances, etc. The library should be able to unpack this array `Variant*` to arguments on the registered function.

i.e.

```
std::function<void(int, float, const char*)> foo;


Variant* args = ...;
size_t numArgs = ...;

/**
 * For example,
 * if (args[0].type == VAR_INT) {
 *     int arg_int = (int)args[0];
 * }
 * would be valid.
 */

foo(args...);
```

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)?

Comment: If the function signature is `void(int, float, const char*)`, you must pass three such objects. But if I understand your question correctly, you want to pass only an `int` if `args[0].type == VAR_INT` for example?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please don't use C-style casting (as in `(int)args[0]`). C-style casting is usually a red flag that you're doing something wrong. Use the C++ `static_cast` or as a last-case `reinterpret_cast`. And if `Variant` have non-explicit conversion operators you don't need a cast at all.

Comment: What should happen if you have variant types as `float, float, const char*` (conversion possible) or `const char*, float, float` (incompatible)

Comment: As for your problem, there's a reason most RPC systems use something like interface description files, which can be used by tools to autogenerate the message dispatcher and wrapper function for the unpacking of the arguments and which calls the real functions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl std::apply requires C++17, and unfortunately I can't use that here.